# Remove only one RightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, navbar, rightbarbuttonitem

In navigation bar I'm adding two right barButtonItems:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[firstBarButton,secondBarButton]];
```

Now when I click over firstBarButtonItem want to remove it. I know when I have only one UIBarButtonItem I do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

How do I do when the rightBarButtonItems are two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set one of them:

`[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:secondBarButton];`

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I had to set self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; and only then [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:secondBarButton]; though